# How to format % and in 2 decimal points?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How do I code format the return data in 2 decimals and with percentage format like 100.00% or 67.39% instead of 100.000000 or 67.391304?

```
SUM(qa.scripting1+qa.conduct1+qa.conduct2+qa.conduct3)*100.0/46 as 'C%'
```

I tried `ROUND()` but I got the error stating that the round function requires 2 to 3 arguments?

```
ROUND(SUM(qa.scripting1+qa.conduct1+qa.conduct2+qa.conduct3)*100.0/46) as 'C%'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do it in SQL Server at all? Just format the display in your user interface.

Comment: The ROUND function requires you to specify the number of decimal places to which the value should be rounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert to a decimal your original value:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), SUM(qa.scripting1+qa.conduct1+qa.conduct2+qa.conduct3)*100.0/46) ) + '%' as 'C%'
```

The first number in the decimal represents the number of digits in the number including decimal places, and the second number represents the number of decimal places.

Comment: This one works just perfect....CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),SUM(qa.scripting1+qa.conduct1+qa.conduct2+qa.conduct3)*100.0/46) as 'C%',

Comment: Oh the Percentage format works as well too! I forgot about that one...LOL

Comment: This one without the *100 actually returns exactly what I was looking for.  CONVERT (VARCHAR(20),CONVERT (DECIMAL(18,2),(SUM(qa.scripting1+qa.conduct1+qa.conduct2+qa.conduct3)*100.0/46))) + '%' as 'C%',

Comment: I've removed the *100

Answer (score 0):

Using Round and Cast will work.  First round to 2 decimal places then convert to a decimal with 2 places to truncate the excess zeros.

```
select cast(Round(yourValue, 2) as decimal(18,2))
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/624)

Comment: Doesn't exist in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @DavidG Good catch, will fix.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass number of decimals in second parameter to round function. For formating you can cast number to money and then cast to varchar:

```
select cast(cast(ROUND(SUM(123.12321)*100.0/46, 2) as money) as varchar) + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Format function

```
select FORMAT(100.0000, 'N' , 'en-us')
```

returns 100.00

and

```
select FORMAT(67.391304, 'N' , 'en-us')
```

returns 67.39

**EDIT**

In version below 2012 you can do this

```
 SELECT CAST(67.391304 AS NUMERIC(10, 2))
```

returns 67.39

Comment: Doesn't exist in SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
select FORMAT(0.391304, '##0.00%')
```

But keep in mind that it implicitly multiplies by 100, so the above will display as 39.13%.